# Chrome developer tool status code and status text shows two different results

Tags: ajax, google-chrome-devtools

When I access Facebook and open Chrome Developer Tool, in **Network** tab, I saw one Ajax request with an odd result.

I saw that line was in red color, and the value in column **Status text** (the one next to **Method** column) was **(failed)**.

However When I clicked on that line and saw in details, it looked something like this:

```
Request URL:https://3-p-06-ash2.channel.facebook.com/pull?channel=p_1000..&format=json
Request Method:GET 
Status Code:200 OK 
Request Headersview source
```

Here is the screenshot (The clicked line is in red color if it is not clicked):

[image]

Comment: If you look carefully, in the left sidebar, it is not the red one that is selected.

Comment: It actually is in red. It turns to be brown when I clicked on it. When I is not clicked it's red.